# Search box not appearing on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm attempting to launch an MVC project on ruby on rails. Having a few issues.
Specifically with the search functionality. This is for a rental website. but unable to get the search box to appear and work.

I have 3 models items, profile and users.
Specifically I want to be able to search users by first name and last name.

Within the profile model I have:

```
def self.search(search)
  where("lastname LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
end
```

Within in the profile_controller I have:

```
def index
  if params[:search]
    @profiles = Profile.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
  else  
   @profiles = Profile.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end
end
```

The application has the following code layout `application.html` page:

```
<p> search </p>
<% form_tag(profiles_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search Profile by Lastname" %>
<%= submit_tag "Search" %>
```

Would also like to extend this further to see what items the users have rented as well.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what specifically isn't working? Are you seeing any errors? What happens vs. what do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

The form is not displaying because it's being evaluated via `<%`, which only executes the code without returning a value to print to the page. Try using `<%=` instead, like so:

```
<%= form_tag(profiles_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In ERB `<% code here %>` tags won't display. You need to change it to `<%= code here %>`.